# Apexcharts right click get element

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I am trying to get the chart element so I can modify it with right click. I am using angular framework. Apexcharts has build in function of left click which is great, but not for right click.

So what I thought to do is add the right click event to the chart element:

```
<apx-chart (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"
              [series]="chartOptions[i].series"
              [chart]="chartOptions[i].chart"
              [colors]="chartOptions[i].colors"
              [title]="chartOptions[i].title"
              [yaxis]="commonOptions.yaxis"
              [dataLabels]="commonOptions.dataLabels"
              [markers]="commonOptions.markers"
              [stroke]="commonOptions.stroke"
              [grid]="commonOptions.grid"
              [xaxis]="commonOptions.xaxis"
              [tooltip]="commonOptions.tooltip"
            ></apx-chart>
```

I have no idea how to reach, where to find and ID, or the chart object it self. I can see "ng-reflect-series" etc., but I am stuck there. This is where I can see the ng-reflect-series:

```
    onRightClick(event) {
        console.log("right clicked on me " + event.currentTarget.attributes);
        return false;
    }
```

Andy advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name is contextmenu. So, your html template code can be something like this:

```html
<div id="chart" class="chart" #chart (contextmenu)="onRightClick(chart, chart.id, $event)"></div>
```

`$event` is an optional parameter but we also give `#chart` element to the function, so we can read out the element and the `chartId`. As for getting the obj of the chart I guess you'll have to read that from Apex docs how to read it.

```js
onRightClick(chart: HTMLElement, chartId: string, event?: Event) {
  console.log(event)
  console.log(chart)
  console.log(chartId)
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/apexcharts-bar-chart-issue-qynzcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts

Comment: Great thanks!, do you by any chance know how I can force redraw of graph? I thought chart.render() would do the trick, but does not seem like...

Comment: I am not that familiar with apex charts, but usually you can trigger change detection when adding changeDedectorRef to constructor and then calling .dedect() other not so good way would be to reassign data to trigger change detector e.g this.chartData = [...this.chartData]